# Negate contextual filters in views

Tags: 7, views

I got a view, which lists nodes of same type, a "Other activities" view, i use this view on a activity node view. However i don't want the node i am currently viewing, to show in the list as well.

So what i did, was to make a contextual filter for nid, and provide a default value of "Content ID of URL", of course now my list only provides me with the currently viewing node.

Isn't there anyway to negate this? So it shows all other nodes, that don't have the nid, og the current?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is an option on contextual filters to exclude the resulting value, rather than limiting the search to that value. Turn on this checkbox, and you should have the results you are seeking.

[image]

Comment: This was a big help.

Comment: **Note:** This option does not appear in all contexts; for example, when using `Comment count` or the `Global Null` item

Answer (score 1):

https://www.drupal.org/project/views_negate

Synopsis

The Views Negate module provides a "Not Equal" to condition for textfield and list field in contextual filter. It works same as exclude option of numeric type field.

A checkbox with "Negate" label is added under "MORE" fieldset. By selecing the Negate option, it applies the "not equal" condition or "not in" if selected "Allow multiple values" option.