# views query I can't workout

Tags: 7, views

I know the query I am trying to achieve. But how to start create it in views using drupal 7 alludes me. This is what I am trying to achieve

SELECT * from Articles where Node IS NOT current Node.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use views contextual filters. Add a contextual filter Content:Nid and provide default value as "Content Id from URL" and select Exclude checkbox in the settings. That's it !!

Comment: Where is this "select negate checkbox in the settings"

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/39898/negate-contextual-filters-in-views  This worked

Comment: I mean Exclude checkbox :-) Great you found the solution !!